# Minimum value of all elements that satisfy a condition in a list

Tags: c#, list, traversal

I have a 2D point class as follows:

```
class Point
{
     public int id_;
     public float x_, y_; 

     public Point(int i, float x, float y)
     {
         id_ = i;
         x_ = x;
         y_ = y;
     }

     public float Distance(Point otherPoint)
     {
         return (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x_ - otherPoint.x_, 2) + Math.Pow(y_ - otherPoint.y_, 2));
     }
}
```

In my main code I have a list of these points. I am presented with a new point. I want to find that point in my list that is the shortest distance from the new point if it satisfies a minimum threshold criteria.

I originally wrote it straightforward by having a minValue (initialized to 1e6) and a minID, traverse through the list to find the minimum value. And outside the traversal, I checked to see if this min value was less than the threshold. That worked.

But I wanted to see if there was a better/cleaner way to implement it, and I ended up with this:

```
var list = new List<Point>();
list.Add(new Point(0, 10.0f, 1.0f));
list.Add(new Point(1, 1.0f, 0.0f));
list.Add(new Point(2, 0.0f, 0.0f));

var p = new Point(3, 0.6f, 0.0f);
var subList = list.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                   .Where(x => (x.item.distance(p) <= 1.0))
                   .Select(x => x.item).ToList();

Point minPoint = subList[Enumerable.Range(0, subList.Count).Aggregate((a, b) => (subList[a].Distance(p) < subList[b].Distance(p) ? a : b))];
Console.WriteLine(minPoint.id_);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do not use `Math.Pow` for calculating squares.

Comment: list.OrderBy(x => x.Distance(p)).First() might be more compact.

Comment: Why do you use `index` in the statement, you never use it anywhere, and you drop it in the end.

Comment: @dustmouse: I'm wondering if one is only interested in the shortest, whether sorting won't make it less efficient.

Comment: Does your implementation work? (It should). If so, then your question is more appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com than here. If it does not work, then your question should not be "is there a better way?", but rather should state clearly what the code you have does and how that's different from what you want (i.e. include an actual problem statement).

Comment: @CommuSoft - Agreed, but right now OP is calling Distance to filter list and then again to compare when finding the index, so it leaves some to be desired in terms of performance anyway.

Comment: Please note, that in 2D space, there could be more than one point that would satisfy your test. Every point on a circle of given radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have some ideas about two solutions of the problem, here is the original class, stripped down of unnecessary underscores. Usually id is unique, so *readonly* and I borrowed Distance method from @CommuSoft's answer, as he is right about that method:

```
class Point
{
    public readonly int id;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public Point(int id, float x, float y)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public float Distance(Point p)
    {
        float dx = this.x - p.x;
        float dy = this.y - p.y;
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}
```

Shared part:

```
        List<Point> list = new List<Point>();
        list.Add(new Point(0, 10.0f, 1.0f));
        list.Add(new Point(1, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        list.Add(new Point(2, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        Point p = new Point(3, 0.6f, 0.0f);
```

Next solution **IpavluVersionA1** is the most efficient in usage of the memory/allocation and computationally efficient as well:

```
        //VersionA1, efficient memory and cpu usage
        Point closest_to_p = null;
        float shortest_d = float.MaxValue;

        //list.ForEach because it is iterating list through for cycle, most effective
        list.ForEach(point =>
        {
            //Distance is computed only ONCE per Point!
            var d = point.Distance(p);
            if (d > 1.0f) return;
            if (closest_to_p == null || shortest_d > d)
            {
                closest_to_p = point;
                shortest_d = d;
            }
        });
        //closest_to_p is cloases point in range with distance 1.0
        //or below or is null, then does not exist
```

Next one is **IpavluVersionA2**, best performance wise:

```
        //VersionA2, most efficient memory and cpu usage
        Point closest_to_p = null;
        float shortest_d = float.MaxValue;
        int max = list.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        {
            var point = list[i];
            var d = point.Distance(p);
            if (d > 1.0f) continue;
            if (closest_to_p == null || shortest_d > d)
            {
                closest_to_p = point;
                shortest_d = d;
            }
        }
        //closest_to_p is closest point in range with distance 1.0
        //or below or is null, then does not exist
```

Another solution, **IpavluVersionB** which is using LINQ approach, has to create new struct object's in order to keep the Point and the distance, but they are most likely created on stack. Computing Distance is done only ONCE, then value is reused!

```
        //versionB
        var null_point =  new KeyValuePair<Point,float>(null, float.PositiveInfinity);
        var rslt_point = 
        list
        .Select(xp =>
        {
            var d = xp.Distance(p);
            return d <= 1.0f ? new KeyValuePair<Point, float>(xp, d) : null_point;
        })
        .Aggregate(null_point, (a, b) =>
        {
            if (a.Key == null) return b;
            if (b.Key == null) return a;
            return a.Value > b.Value ? b : a;
        }, x => x.Key);
```

`rslt_point` is null or instance of most closest point to `p`.

**BENCHMARK:**

- must be built in Release Mode,
- must run without debugging, outside of VisualStudio,
- test is running 5 times for two scenarios,
- scenario X: 3 items, 10 million times, all methods, time in miliseconds,
- scenario Y: 3mil itmes, 1 time, all methods, time in milliseconds,

[the code is here](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v)

**BechmarkREsults:**

- B  - number of iterations over list,
- I  - number of items in list,
- all numbers in milliseconds,
- CommuSoft is solution from CommuSoft's answer,
- Ivan Stoev proposed solution with anonymous types, behave similarly to VersionA2 with struct's,
- **Clearly IpavluVersionA2 is best performance wise.**

B[10000000] I[3]: CommuSoft: 3521 IpavluA1: 371 IpavluA2: 195 IpavluB: 1587

B[10000000] I[3]: CommuSoft: 3466 IpavluA1: 371 IpavluA2: 194 IpavluB: 1583

B[10000000] I[3]: CommuSoft: 3463 IpavluA1: 370 IpavluA2: 194 IpavluB: 1583

B[10000000] I[3]: CommuSoft: 3465 IpavluA1: 370 IpavluA2: 194 IpavluB: 1582

B[10000000] I[3]: CommuSoft: 3471 IpavluA1: 372 IpavluA2: 196 IpavluB: 1583

B[1](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v) I[3000000]: CommuSoft: 919 IpavluA1: 21 IpavluA2: 17 IpavluB: 75

B[1](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v) I[3000000]: CommuSoft: 947 IpavluA1: 21 IpavluA2: 17 IpavluB: 75

B[1](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v) I[3000000]: CommuSoft: 962 IpavluA1: 21 IpavluA2: 17 IpavluB: 75

B[1](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v) I[3000000]: CommuSoft: 969 IpavluA1: 21 IpavluA2: 17 IpavluB: 75

B[1](http://pastebin.com/Tvk4B85v) I[3000000]: CommuSoft: 961 IpavluA1: 21 IpavluA2: 17 IpavluB: 75

Comment: I'm wondering, in your version A, once you decided to try non Linq approach, why the heck are you using  `List.ForEach` instead of `foreach` or `for`

Comment: **foreach** is usually little slower, has to do more things, **list.ForEach** is just inside list, so why not, works usually better than **foreach**, but **for** is here the winner :), and that is **VersionA2**.

Comment: Thank you for your efficient collation of the results.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use the following, which does O(N) Distance calculations and O(N) comparisons:

```
var closest = list.Select(item => new { item, distance = item.Distance(p) })
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a.distance <= b.distance ? a : b);
var closestPt = closest.distance <= 1.0 ? closest.item : null;
```

Comment: Yes, I considered this one, but unfortunately, there is the issue with "new" keyword for a large number of points. The **anonymous types are class types**, so for every point **new instance of the anonymous class has to be created on the heap!**. That does not feel right for 2D points, there could be millions or more...

Comment: @ipavlu I don't like it either, could have used `KeyValuePair` struct, but `Select` really creates just one short lived object + the one used to hold the seed of `Aggregate`, so there shouldn't be a problem with large list, no?

Comment: I must go to bed:), instead testing:). But results suggest that your solution is about as performant as mine VersionB. If running on 3 items 10mil times, your solution is about 1400ms, mine versionB is 1580ms. If running on 3mil items once, your version is 119ms, mine versionB is 74ms. So it behaves similarly, but could all different story on heavy loaded CPU.  Now interesting thing, the VersionA1 of mine takes 374ms if ran 10mil times or takes 22ms if ran once on 3mil items. VersionA1 is even better, 196ms and 17ms.

Comment: You must test list whether there are any items. Aggregate in this generic version does not like that. Strangely enough, the version with seed allows to handle empty list but is also little slower...

Comment: I did more tests of the version with struct and the version with anonymous type(class), it provided interesting numbers. For example test on a list with 3 mil items, struct version took consistently about 74ms, anonymous type version was from 78ms to 119ms, and most of the times it took something near 119ms. It seems this random behaviour is an effect of the heap.

Comment: @ipavlu I like your entusiasm and thinking for performance and heap allocations, however the key point in this question wasn't the performance.  It was obvious from the beginning that the fastest way will be using a plain `for`  loop (as you already discovered after a few attempts - see my comment of your first post). CommuSoft.A might be the slowest in this particular case, but in fact is the only method that would work with IEnumerable and also with all IQueryable providers which translate what you write to a db SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can be improved:

1. Drop the first `Select` statement, since it has no use? You don't do anything with this point; This allows you to drop the second `Select` statement as well.
2. Don't use `ToList`: you are not interested in constructing this list anyway;
3. `Math.Pow` is a method used for arbitrary powers, it is furthermore not that much precise, use `x*x` instead of `Math.Pow(x,2)`;
4. You made some small errors with respect to caps, `Points` instead of `Points`, `Distance` instead of `Distance`;

A way to obtain your `Point`, that is not the *absolute most effecient one* is using the following statement:

```
class Point {

     public int id_;
     public float x_, y_; 

     public Point(int i, float x, float y) {
         id_ = i;
         x_ = x;
         y_ = y;
     }

     public float Distance(Point otherPoint) {
         float dx = this.x_-otherPoint.x_;
         float dy = this.y_-otherPoint.y_;
         return (float)Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
     }
}
```

with a potential query:

```
var minPoint = list.Where(x => x.Distance(p) <= 1.0).OrderBy(x => x.Distance(p)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `null` if no such item exists (that satisfies the `Where` clause). This will however, in most cases, not be the absolute most efficient implementation.

---

Another way is to first implement an extension method:

```
public static class Utils {

    public static T MinBy<T,R> (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,R> f) where R : IComparable<R> {
        IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator();
        if(!e.MoveNext()) {
            throw new Exception("You need to provide at least one element.");
        }
        T min = e.Current;
        R minf = f(min);
        while(e.MoveNext()) {
            T x = e.Current;
            R xf = f(x);
            if(minf.CompareTo(xf) > 0) {
                min = x;
                minf = xf;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

}
```

Then you can use:

```
var minPoint = list.Where(x => x.Distance(p) <= 1.0).MinBy(x => x.Distance(p));
```

This method runs in *O(n)* and is thus probably one of the most efficient ones.

---

**Benchmarks**

I've tested both the two methods of @ipavlu and myself, although with the small testset you gave, so the results are not *really scientifically valid*, and executed these using the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> DateTime dt=DateTime.Now; for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { var minPoint = list.Where(x => x.Distance(p) <= 1.0).OrderBy(x => x.Distance(p)).FirstOrDefault(); }; DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now; Console.WriteLine(dt2-dt); 
(1,68): warning CS0219: The variable `minPoint' is assigned but its value is never used
00:00:09.3165310    
csharp> DateTime dt=DateTime.Now; for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { var minPoint = list.Where(x => x.Distance(p) <= 1.0).MinBy(x => x.Distance(p)); }; DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now; Console.WriteLine(dt2-dt);  
(1,68): warning CS0219: The variable `minPoint' is assigned but its value is never used
00:00:03.3658400
csharp> DateTime dt=DateTime.Now; for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { Point closest_to_p = null;float shortest_d = float.MaxValue;list.ForEach(point =>{var d = point.Distance(p);if (d > 1.0f) return;if (closest_to_p == null || shortest_d > d){closest_to_p = point;shortest_d = d;}}); }; DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;Console.WriteLine(dt2-dt);                                       
00:00:10.4554550
csharp> DateTime dt=DateTime.Now; for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { var null_point =  new KeyValuePair<Point,float>(null, float.PositiveInfinity);var rslt_point = list.Select(xp =>{var d = xp.Distance(p);return d <= 1.0f ? new KeyValuePair<Point, float>(xp, d) : null_point;}).Aggregate(null_point, (a, b) =>{if (a.Key == null) return b;if (b.Key == null) return a;return a.Value > b.Value ? b : a;}, x => x.Key); }; DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now; Console.WriteLine(dt2-dt);
(1,146): warning CS0219: The variable `rslt_point' is assigned but its value is never used
00:00:18.5995530
```

This thus results in some *insignificant results*:

```
CommuSoft.A 00:00:09.3165310
CommuSoft.B 00:00:03.3658400
ipavlu.A    00:00:10.4554550
ipavlu.B    00:00:18.5995530
```

Furthermore note that these work in debug mode, and that compilers can sometimes find useful optimizations.

Comment: As you already noted in your comment above, this is less efficient, due to the overhead of sorting. On relatively large sequences or repeated iterations, this could in fact be significant and unacceptable.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I've implemented a `MinBy` extension method (see updated answer), that runs in *O(n)* (given `f` runs in constant time, etc).

Comment: @ipavlu: well mind that constructing an object that stores the distance requires a malloc, which is log m in the size of the memory, so by recomputing the chances are this will be more efficient, not to say that determining the absolute most efficient algorithm is undecidable anyway.

Comment: @ipavlu: I've tested both your two and my two methods with the given sample list 10M times

Comment: Sorry, but no, in C# there is **no such thing as precise performance measurements in Debug mode**. I made tests of my own, two versions, 3 items in list, 10mil times and 3militems in list once, all for your method and 3 methods of mine, please look into my answer for the benchmark and code. My measurements do tell different story...